# How to use issues list from iTunes Connect (Newsstand button)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect, newsstand-kit

I'm trying to set up my newsstand application for iOS. 
I've made Auto-Renewable Subscription In-App Purchases for subscription, I've made Non-Consumable In-App Purchases for single issues, so it's ok, but one thing still bothers me.

iTunes Connect Developer Guide says ["You can enable your app for Newsstand from the app summary page for an app by clicking Newsstand."](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/14_Newsstand/Newsstand.html), but I still unable to get the purpose of this. What's the use of issues I add under this button?

Is there is a way to get this list of issues from my app? Or why it is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for purposes of covers being shown in iTunes Preview / App Store. If you don't use it at all, the covers won't change, however using Atom Feed to update them seems to be better solution.

You can find how to use it here: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/NewsstandAtomFeedSpecification.pdf

Comment: So, I could not use it from my application?

Comment: AFAIK not, why would you like to do that?

Comment: You are right, stupid question. But I still can not find list of issues in itunes for another newsstand apps. Authors did not provide it or itunes just did not show it and itunes just use only the last cover?

Comment: iTunes shows only the latest cover, hovere you can find some piece of information in iTunes Preview in the "top in-app purchases" section.